# How to build a URL from a set of LARAVEL subcategories?

Tags: php, laravel

Please explain how to correctly build a URL from a variety of subcategories?

I have a page - all categories (general menu).

```
// Route
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
```

```
// Controller
public function index()
```

from this page, I have to go to `ru/category/clothes/womens`, for this I have:

```
// Route
Route::get('/category/{alias?}', 'CategoryController@one')->name('category.one');
```

```
// Controller
public function one($alias, Request $request)
```

```
// Link
<a title="{{ $v['name'] }}" href="{{ route('category.one', $v['url']) }}">
```

but I can't pass the parameter (clothes/womens). 404 was not found  , maybe because `$v ['url']` is not a laravel object.

**What should I do then?**

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Where did you set `$v`?  Have you looked at what `$alias` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('/category/{alias?}', 'CategoryController@one')->where('alias', '(.*)')->name('category.one');
```